# Programming with scientific standards in mind

Tags: scientific-computing

I'm a mediocre programmer trying to improve his skills. Especially I'm interested in programming for scientific purposes, considering questions like the quantifiability of robustness, accuracy, performance, stability of code in general.

A google search didn't bring up much on good practices or well established standards. So do you know of any publications (books, papers, websites) that discuss the topic in more detail?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hmm, difficult. I'm not able to rework the question, since it's goal is to collect information to get me started on the topic. Probably there is lots of information out there in the net, but as a non native english speaker it's sometimes difficult to find the right keywords to ask.  

But I also understand that rules are necessary to organize a huge plattform like stackoverflow. :)

Comment: You could begin by clarifying "for scientific purposes". Are we talking about simulation algorithms or controller code for scientific equipment or what? Apart from that, any work on programming best-practices probably also applies to scientific programs.

Comment: @Cephalopod: I am an aerospace student working on his final thesis. My subject is to develop a software for the preliminary design of rockets. The topic covers general mechanical engineering, but also algorithms for thermodynamics, aerodynamics and much more. My main problem is to convince the members of our institute that certain programming standards are needed to write "good" software. Atm nearly all software written inhouse is done in Matlab. Allthough Matlab is a neat tool, it lacks some features that I would consider crucial for a complex application.

Comment: So in my thesis Im trying to explain how important OOP, type safety, documentation, revision control, a layer-architecture and all those well established practices are. As I covered all the basics, I started to wonder if there are more sophisticated ways to evaluate the quality of code. When writing algorithms there are usually some clever mathematical ways to proof the correctness/robustness of a model, but what about the general architecture of a program?

Comment: How to proove that a n-tier design works, or how to implement "fail proven" ways to validate calculations? There must be some best practices on how to ensure (or quantify) the quality of a program on a more unspecific, abstract level...

Comment: There are ways to semi-objectively evaluate architecture and quality of code: There are tools that look for [code smells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), then there are (object-oriented) code metrics ([*the* book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540244295); [a paper](http://www.literateprogramming.com/ooapply.pdf)). Maybe you can ask on programmers.SE for what would be good arguments to switch from matlab to OOP.

Comment: @Cephalopod: The paper is excellent! Very interesting and it's even aerospace related. Thank you!!